I'm having trouble configuring CORS
I'm working on a frontend application using React with Redux and a backend in NestJS with Firebase. I'm facing a CORS issue that I can't seem to resolve.
I've configured CORS on the backend, but I'm still getting this error:

has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled. in the console.

I'm honestly out of ideas on what might be causing this. Any help would be appreciated!
Configured backend:
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.enableCors({
    origin: ['http://localhost:3000'],
    methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE', // Permitir os métodos GET, POST e PUT
    allowedHeaders: 'X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept, Observe, Authorization',
    credentials: true,
  });
  await app.listen(4000);
}
bootstrap();

https://github.com/vsdiaman/backend-chatPDF
I've been stuck with this issue for three days now and still no solution. I've tried configuring CORS both on the backend and the frontend, but nothing seems to work. I expected the backend configuration to solve the problem, but it hasn't. I even attempted to adjust the rules in Firebase, but I'm still facing the same issue. I really can't seem to find a way out of this problem and would appreciate any help. Thanks!

First check your port of your frontend if its the correct link
Check if it works on localhost:3000 and not on some other port
From my experience your code looks correct as i have used similar code except not mentioning headers

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
